# jquery mobile selectmenu-custom-filter special characters

Tags: jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

I am testing a jquery mobile filterable costum select in my project http://www.promocaototal.pt/cidades1.php it's all working fine but the issue is that the cities names are in Portuguese and when applying the filter it does not recognize the special charactes returning an empty search for names like Águeda when typing Agueda. Can anyone one point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to append `data-filtertext="Agueda"` to the Águeda option.